# Regex: capture between delimiters, with optional end delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string types:

```
- Lorem ipsum - dolor sit amet
- Lorem ipsum - dolor sit: amet
...
```

```
1. Lorem ipsum - dolor sit amet (1.5)
2. consectetur: adipiscing elit (4.5)
...
```

The portion with the two digits between parentheses is optional, so... how can I capture the portion between the list markers ("- ", or "1. ", "2. ", etc) and the start of the first parentheses " (" with a single regular expression? In Javascript.

So far I've tried:

```
[a-z](.*)(?=\s\()
```

which captures "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" from "1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (1.5)".

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The tested strings can also include ":" and "-" characters.

Comment: Try `text.match(/^(?:-|\d+\.).*(?:\r?\n(?!-|\d+\.).*)*/gm)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?:-|\d+\.)\s*(.*?)(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?$/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aAeYjK/2). If the text is a single line of text, remove `m` at the end.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line/string
- `(?:-|\d+\.)` - a `-` or 1+ digits and a `.`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?` - an optional sequence of 0+ whitespaces, `(`, any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`, a `)`
- `$` end of string/line.

JS demo:

```js
var text = '- Lorem ipsum - dolor sit amet\n- Lorem ipsum - dolor sit: amet\n..\n1. Lorem ipsum - dolor sit amet (1.5)\n2. consectetur: adipiscing elit (4.5)';
var rx = /^(?:-|\d+\.)\s*(.*?)(?:\s*\([^()]*\))?$/gm;
var m, result=[];
while(m=rx.exec(text)) {
  result.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(result);
```